# Scan dom/webpage after certain pattern and get domtag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I write a small chrome extension which includes adding buttons add specific positions.

These positions are mostly random and can't be determined with normal css/jQuery selectors.
I need to scan the whole page for a certain text pattern (regex).
After I found matches I need to get the dom tag where the text is in.

I tried parsing the whole source with `body.innerHtml` but I cant get the tag obj afterwards.

Any ideas on how to accomplish such a task are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you could use [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) for this.

```
$(":contains('Your Text')")
```

For finding text using a regular expression use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
var regex = new RegExp("Your Text");
$("*").filter(function () {
  return regex.test($(this).text()); 
});
```

Comment: That would be a choice, when I am searching for a static text. But I need to search for a pattern (regex). E.g. `/\d-xyz-\d+/`

Comment: Then the only method I can think of is `.filter()`. See updated answer

Comment: Indeed - even if this will be really slow it could work. Thank you!